# Complex array to vararg via spread operator in Kotlin does not work

Tags: java, arrays, list, kotlin, variadic-functions

I'm working with Kotlin (Jetpack compose) with the google routes API.

I have a problem with the snapToRoads function. It accepts only "vararg LatLng!" (Java class)

I have tried with Array and List and the spread operator "*" and .toTypeArray but this is just working with simple variables, but not for LatLng.

```
com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng
@Contract(pure = true)  
public LatLng(     double latitude,
    double longitude )
```

Error from "snapToRoads" function from code below:
None of the following functions can be called with the arguments supplied.
snapToRoads(GeoApiContext!, vararg LatLng!) defined in com.google.maps.RoadsApi
snapToRoads(GeoApiContext!, Boolean, vararg LatLng!) defined in com.google.maps.RoadsApi

The GeoApiContext is working perfectly with other calls without varargs.
How can I hand over my variables?

Here are my build.gradle.kts dependencies:

```
implementation("androidx.core:core-ktx:1.12.0")

    implementation("androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.8.1")
    implementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics")
    implementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview")
    implementation("androidx.compose.material3:material3")

    testImplementation("junit:junit:4.13.2")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation(platform("androidx.compose:compose-bom:2023.03.00"))
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling")
    debugImplementation("androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest")
    implementation("androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1")
    implementation("androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1")
    //Maps
    implementation ("com.google.maps.android:maps-compose:2.9.0")
    implementation ("com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0")
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1")

//Lifecycle
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.2")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:2.6.2")
    implementation ("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.2")


    implementation("androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.2")
    //DirectionsAPI+
    implementation ("com.google.maps:google-maps-services:2.2.0")
    implementation ("org.slf4j:slf4j-simple:1.7.25")
```

My Kotlin function:

```
fun getRoadsSnapped(
        // First: Snap to Roads to get placeIds
        dirlist: List<LatLng>,
        callback: (Array<Double>) -> Unit

    ){

        // Handle Pathlist that it is below 100 in size
        var tmpPathlist: Array<LatLng> = emptyArray()
        var divider: Int = 1

        //RoadsApi only allowed 100 paths in snapToRoads. Reduce them evenly.
        if (dirlist.size > 100){
            divider = ceil((dirlist.size.toFloat() / 100f)).roundToInt()
        }

        for (i in dirlist.indices step divider){
            tmpPathlist += dirlist[i]
        }

        println("Size of handed over Array: " + tmpPathlist.size.toString())

        val snapped = RoadsApi.snapToRoads(mGeoApiContext, *tmpPathlist)

        // [...] setCallback...
     }
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem:

There are two variable types named "LatLng".

LatLng(**latitude**: Double, **longitude**: Double)
in com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.2.0

and

LatLng(**lat**: Double, **lng**: Double)
in com.google.maps:google-maps-services:2.2.0

Both variables are incompatible. So my working code looks like this:

```
fun getRoadsSnapped(
    // First: Snap to Roads to get placeIds
    dirlist: List<LatLng>,
    callback: (Array<Double>) -> Unit

){

    // Handle Pathlist that it is below 100 in size

    // Right dependency variable
    var tmpPathlist: Array<com.google.maps.model.LatLng> = emptyArray()
    var divider: Int = 1

    //RoadsApi only allowed 100 paths in snapToRoads. Reduce them evenly.
    if (dirlist.size > 100){
        divider = ceil((dirlist.size.toFloat() / 100f)).roundToInt()
    }

    for (i in dirlist.indices step divider){
        // copy by hand
        tmpPathlist += com.google.maps.model.LatLng(dirlist[i].latitude, dirlist[i].longitude)
        
    }

    println("Size of handed over Array: " + tmpPathlist.size.toString())

    val snapped = RoadsApi.snapToRoads(mGeoApiContext, *tmpPathlist )

    // [...] setCallback...

   }
```

That is, when you focus just to the obvious thing, that was that I'm new to Kotlin and varargs.

The Kotlin "*" is working.

I will ask the google team, if this has some reasons.